# Linux LVM stripe gives the same amount of free space vs. Linear?

Tags: linux, lvm

Linux LVM stripe gives the same amount of free space vs. Linear?

Comment: Please could you put some more effort into your question. It's really unclear what you're actually trying to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between linear and striped volumes does not affect capacity; it affects how the data is physically placed onto volumes.

Imagine two decks of cards.

With a linear volume of two disks then you can think of the overall volume as having the second deck added to the end of the first.  So when you deal them out you'll deal all the first deck and then you'll deal the second deck.

With a striped volume of two disks you can think of it like two decks of cards where a card from deck 1 is used then a card from deck 2, then the second card from deck 1, then the second card from deck 2...

In both cases you have 2 decks of cards and the same amount of cards to deal out, but *how* you deal them changes.

There are performance implications (with a stripe data can be sent to/from two different disks, so it can be faster) but it really gets complicated very quickly in anything other than the simplest of use cases.